Fedora Server - Docker - NGINX - SSL configuration works in LAN by not with IP public
I'm trying to configure the SSL connection with my server. The point is, I've have a server wiht Fedora Server 39 distro with Docker installed. Docker holds on several container with differents APIs and there is a one more container with Nginx as Reverse Proxy.
The configuration of the Nginx container is (default.conf file):
server {
  listen 80;
  listen  [::]:80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location / {
     root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     index  index.html index.htm;
   }

  location /common/ {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.100.5:46000/common/;
  }
  
  location /swagger/ {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.100.5:46000/swagger/;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
       root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
  
   access_log /etc/nginx/log/http/access/register.log;
   error_log /etc/nginx/log/http/error/register.log;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   listen [::]:443 ssl;
   server_name localhost;

   http2 on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/certificate.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/key.key;

   location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index-https.html;
   }

   location /swagger/ {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.100.5:46000/swagger/index.html;
   }
  
   access_log /etc/nginx/log/https/access/register.log;
   error_log /etc/nginx/log/https/error/register.log;
}

This container recives the request and redirect them to the endpoint. In addition, the firewall of the server is configured:
sudo firewall-cmd --list-port
Returns
80/tcp 443/tcp 46000/tcp
Theoretically everything is ready to work (atleast the big details), in fact, when you call the server out of the LAN (http://example.net) the welcome page of nginx appear but when you call by HTTPS (https://example.net) this doesn't happens and obtein the error ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE.
The strange thing about all this, is that when I made the call from LAN (https://192.168.100.5) the reuqest is success.
Any advice or hints which help to finish the cofiguration of the server?
Thank so much in advance!
I tried dofferents configurations of the default.conf and change the ports to SSL.

Finally our provider of cloud services has a "unknown" redirect action over 443 port... For this reason it was impossible to reach the endpoint!
